# Testing hardware with node.js and jasmine

Tags: node.js, io, jasmine, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm starting to learn some hardware programming with RaspberryPi, and am building a node.js framework to make it easier to write programs to control I/O on my Pi (starting with GPIO).

I'm using jasmine-node for testing.

right now when my code says something like

```
on = function(){
   gpio.open(pin,"output",function(err){    
        this.getVal();
        gpio.write(pin,1,function(err){
            console.log(pin + ' should be on now');
            gpio.close(pin);
        });
    });
}
```

I actually look at the RaspberryPi and check that the LED on 'pin' has actually turned on. That isn't exactly automated testing.

Any suggestions for how to stub something like GPIO, I2C, etc. etc.

To clarify, I'm looking to tes RaspberryPi code without it being hooked up to a RaspberryPi.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will blink an LED. It is setup for pin 18 so make sure you do gpio-admin export 18 before running your script. Notice that I have also added process.on('SIGINT') this will allow you to stop the program by using ctrl + c which will close the pin. After stoping your program it is recommended that you unexport the pin so run gpio-admin unexport 18

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");
var status = 0;
var timerId =0;
gpio.open(18, "output", function(err) {        // Open pin 18 for output
timerId =setInterval(function(){
gpio.read(18,function(err,value){
    console.log(value);

gpio.write(18, 1, function() {            // Set pin 18 high (1)


});


});
setTimeout(function(){
    gpio.read(18,function(err,value){
            console.log(value);
            gpio.write(18,0,function(){

            });
    });
},500);
},1000);
});
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
console.log('Got SIGINT.');
gpio.close(18);                       // Now close pin 18
clearTimeout(timerId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Warren, I'm not sure how this is any better than just looking at device or outputting to the log and viewing the output. I was looking for something more like a test-suite for testing.

Comment: You can use webiopi for just testing the pins or turning them on or off in or out https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/INSTALL

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what I'm looking for Warren, I'm trying to test the code WITHOUT being connected directly to a RaspberryPi. I'll update the question to make it more clear, but I don't think there is such a tool as yet.